# api request not working node

Tags: javascript, node.js, post, postman

I have this function in my api:

```
app.post('/api/create-project'),(req, res) => {
  console.log("hejhej");
  var newProject = new projectModel();
  newProject.questions = doc.sort((prev, current) => (prev.version > current.version) ? prev : current)[0];
  newProject.owner = req.body.owner;
  newProject.projectName = req.body.projectName;
  newProject.date = Date.now();
  newProject.version = 1.0;
  console.log(newProject)
  res.send(newProject)
  .catch(error => console.log(error))
}
```

But when i try to call it with postman and get a result i get this:

```
Cannot POST /api/create-project
```

My body I'm sending looks like this:

```
{
    "owner": "test",
    "projectname": "testing"
}
```

towards: http://localhost:3000/api/create-project

Can not seem to figure it out, it's probably something silly but..

Comment: Guess your `app.post('/api/create-project'),(req, res) => {` should be declared as **`app.post('/api/create-project', (req, res) => {....});`**

Comment: Yep, the first `)` is supposed to be moved after the very last `}`

Comment: comma operator strikes again!!! (well, if the comma operator weren't a valid a true operator, the code would not parse :p ) - of course, using a code linter, you would get a warning like `Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression.` - which may have made it obvious :p

Comment: This worked! Thank you guys so very much!

Answer (score -2):

app.post('/api/create-project',(req, res) => { console.log("hejhej"); var newProject = new projectModel(); newProject.questions = doc.sort((prev, current) => (prev.version > current.version) ? prev : current)[0]; newProject.owner = req.body.owner; newProject.projectName = req.body.projectName; newProject.date = Date.now(); newProject.version = 1.0; console.log(newProject) res.send(newProject) .catch(error => console.log(error)) });

Try this

Comment: we should pass route and controller  to get(),put(),post(),delete() ,i found he was wrong that he just passed route arguement and not the function() and i corrected that changes and send him  ex: app.post('/api/drivers',driverController.create); .Please correct me if i am wrong